# If real $x$ and $y$ satisfy $x^2+y^2-4x+10y+20=0$, then prove that $y+7-3\sqrt{2}\le x\le y+7+3\sqrt{2}$

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

> Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 + y^2 - 4x + 10y + 20 = 0$. Prove that 
>   $$y + 7 - 3\sqrt{2} \le x \le y + 7 + 3\sqrt{2}$$

I'm struggling with that problem. I've recognized that the given equation is one of a circle, namely; $$(x-2)^2 + (y+5)^2 = 9$$

And what needs to be proven can be derived to the form: $$7-3\sqrt{2}\le x-y\le 7 + 3\sqrt{2} \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad (x-y)^2 - 14(x-y) + 31 \le 0$$

But I really can't find the correlation between what's given and what has to be proven! Also, I'm wondering if this problem can be generalized for any circle parameters, something like an universal interval of $x-y$ for any circle. Any help is apprecatiated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $x-y=c$

Use $x=y+c$   to form a Quadratic Equation  in $y$

As $y$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

One may replace $y$ with $x-c$ as well.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It really was that simple! And it can be generalized for any circle as well! I found your answer the most intuitive and simplistic!

Comment: @D.Petrov, Not only circle, ellipse as well. Please find my other answer as well

Answer (score 3):

Think about it geometrically; $x-y = c$ is a line parallel to $y=x$, and you want to find all such $c$ that makes the line intersect the circle.

This makes it clear that you only need to find the two lines that are tangent, and the tangency points are at $(2,-5) \pm (\frac{3}{\sqrt 2}, -\frac{3}{\sqrt 2})$ (just draw two lines tangent and you'll see how this is clear). Compute the values of $x-y$, and your answer will appear.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, this approach works as well!

Comment: you mean $(2,\color{red}-5)$, correct?

Comment: My bad, i’ve fixed that typo up now.

Answer (score 2):

WLOG $x=2+3\cos t, y=-5+3\sin t$

$$x-y=7+3(\cos t-\sin t)$$

Now $$(\cos t-\sin t)^2+(\cos t+\sin t)^2=2$$

$$\implies(\cos t-\sin t)^2\le2$$

Answer (score 2):

Writing $u = x - 2$ and $v = y + 5$ shows that the problem is equivalent to proving that if $u^2 + v^2 = 9,$ then $|u - v| \leqslant 3\sqrt2.$ We have $$
(u - v)^2 + (u + v)^2 = (u^2 - 2uv + v^2) + (u^2 + 2uv + v^2) = 2(u^2 + v^2) = 18,
$$
therefore $(u - v)^2 \leqslant 18,$ and the result follows by taking square roots.

More generally, for the circle $(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = r^2,$ if we write $u = x - a$ and $v = y - b,$ essentially the same argument gives $(u - v)^2 \leqslant 2r^2,$ whence $|u - v| \leqslant r\sqrt2,$ i.e.
$$
a - b -r\sqrt2 \leqslant x - y \leqslant a - b + r\sqrt2.
$$

Comment: What might be most helpful is to think of the problem as related to a change of coordinate system: first translating so that $(a,b)$ is the new origin, then rotating from $(u,v)$ to $(\xi,\eta),$ where the $\xi$-axis is $45^\circ$ anticlockwise from the $u$-axis, and the $\eta$-axis similarly from the $v$-axis. This rotation of axes is given by the equations $\xi=(u+v)/\sqrt2$ and $\eta=(v-u)/\sqrt2.$ In terms of $(\xi,\eta)$ the equation of the circle becomes $\xi^2+\eta^2=r^2.$ It is then a very familiar fact that the $\eta$ coordinate satisfies the inequalities $-r\leqslant\eta\leqslant r.$